# intentservice doesn't work as I expected it to

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a small app that would receive ringer mode change broadcasts and then display a small toast whenever it is received. Although it can be achieved by using only a single activity, I intend to use an intentservice. However, the intentservice I made is making the app crash everytime, and there hasn't been a single successful run.

The MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.servicepractice;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.android.servicepractice.AudioService");
    startService(serviceIntent);

}
}
```

The AudioService.java file

```
package com.example.android.servicepractice;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioService extends IntentService{

public BroadcastReceiver receiver;

//First requirement is a constructor
public AudioService(){
    super("AudioService");
}

//This is the function that is called when the service is created
@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    //Work that needs to be done
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Mode Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
 }
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.servicepractice">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".AudioService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am new to android, and this is my first time using intentservices, so I wanted to know what would be the better alternative for use here, Services or IntentServices? Also, what am I doing wrong here that the app keeps on crashing?

Comment: There could be a ton of issues. The **real** thing here isn't others to ask to review your code, to maybe spot the issue, but to learn how to **debug** this problem. Start here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash

Comment: I think I asked this because I wanted to learn first, I just need someone to guide me and point out where I went wrong. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, it is possible that a more experienced Android person notices some "obvious" issue in your code. But basically you are making yourself dependent on that. Whereas, most likely, your problem is caused by some basic problem, which should be easy to identify, once you start logging into log files for example. That is the whole point: it will take you some time to learn how to debug app crashes. But you will spent that time anyway, and it is better you do that upfront.